# conditional ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

In example like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in ['1','2']" id="tab-{{i}}">
    <div ng-repeat="e in myCollection"> 
     </div>
</div>
```

In the first iteration of the second `ng-repeat` I'd like to get first element of `myCollection` and in the second iteration I'd like to get the rest of the collection:

So why can't I do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in ['1','2']" id="tab-{{i}}">
    <div ng-repeat="e in i == 1 ? _.first(myCollection) : _.rest(myCollection, 1)"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

underscore.js methods are so helpful, but unfortunately this trick wouldn't work.

So how can I do something like that, right in the markup without involving code-behind javascript?
I know, I know it's probably ain't right thing to do, nevertheless I'm curious if it's possible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular [expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) look like javascript, but are actually a subset of it, and do not allow any kind of control flow statements in them. To accomplish what you want to do, you'l need to set up your inner ng-repeat arrays in a controller.